# Showing Factor Groups are Simple; Subgroups of Solvable Groups are Solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, simple-groups, solvable-groups

I'm aware this post is related to many other posts on proving that subgroups of solvable groups are solvable. However, there's a certain claim that is necessary to show based on the definition of solvability that I'm using. In the other posts, this part of the proof isn't demonstrated because of the difference in this definition.

In this post, a composition series $\{H_i\}$ of a group $G$ means the $\{H_i\}$ form a subnormal series with each $H_i/H_{i-1}$ simple.
Also, for a group $G$ to be solvable in this post, it means there exists a composition series $\{H_i\}$ of $G$ such that all the factor groups $H_i/H_{i-1}$ are abelian.

My goal is to show that if $G$ is solvable and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is solvable. I got this exercise from Fraleigh's *A First Course In Abstract Algebra* 7th edition on p.320 (exercise 26). I used the hint that suggested I consider the subnormal series $\{H_i \cap K\}$ of $K$. I'm having difficulty showing that the factor groups are all simple.

Another part of the hint suggests to use that $H_{i-1}(H_i \cap K) \leq H_i$. Furthermore, by the second isomorphism theorem, $(H_i \cap K)/(H_{i-1} \cap K) \cong H_{i-1}(H_i \cap K)/H_{i-1}$. It's tempting to assert that since $H_{i-1}(H_i \cap K)/H_{i-1} \leq H_i/H_{i-1}$, and $H_i/H_{i-1}$ is simple, then $H_{i-1}(H_i \cap K)/H_{i-1}$ is simple and therefore $(H_i \cap K)/(H_{i-1} \cap K)$ is simple by their being isomorphic. But, this is flawed since a subgroup of a simple group isn't generally simple.

With that said, how does one show that the series $\{H_i \cap K\}$ has all simple factor groups, i.e. that all $(H_i \cap K)/(H_{i-1} \cap K)$ are simple? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You know that $H_i / H_{i-1}$ is abelian AND simple. What kinds of groups are both abelian and simple? Specifically, what can you say about their subgroups?

Comment: Your definition of solvable is not very good. It works for finite groups, but does not generalize well. The integers would not be solvable in tnat definition.

Comment: @Chris Right, so the factor group has no proper nontrivial subgroups so that the factor group is either a repetition (i.e. it's a repeated group so remove it from the series) or it is the whole of $H_i/H_{i-1}$ and is therefore simple. Thanks!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin True, is a more generalizable definition just one that doesn't demand the series be composition? Or is there more to that?

Comment: The usual definition is that there be a subnormal series in which every quotient is abelian. This is equivalent to asking for a *normal* series in which every quotient is abelian, so this is sometimes also given as the definition. That a subnormal series can be refined to a composition series only holds in general for finite groups, so definitions that should encompass both finite and infinite groups generally do not require composition series.